# How to position text below image in Flutter if doesn't fit on the side?

Tags: dart, flutter

I don't know how to concatenate column and row together so it is in shape of "L" around image.

```
This is text. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This is text. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXimageXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This is text. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This is text. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This is text.This is text.This is text.This is text.
This is text.This is text.This is text.This is text.
This is text.This is text.This is text.This is text.
```

Comment: Can you share your code and the final result you need?

Answer (score -1):

You would need to nest rows and columns.

example:

```
     void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
     }
   }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
   }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Text"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is text.',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/kitty-551554__340.jpg"),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'This is text.',
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'This is text.',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'This is text.',
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'This is text.',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
  }
```

Comment: What if text is paragraph which is unknown length ?